# Make simple servlet filter work with @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, filter, exception, spring-security, spring-boot

I've a simple filter just to check if a request contains a special header with static key - no user auth - just to protect endpoints. The idea is to throw an `AccessForbiddenException` if the key does not match which then will be mapped to response with a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. However I can't make it work. My `@ExceptionHandler` isn't called.

**ClientKeyFilter**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller

import javax.servlet.*
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

@Controller //I know that @Component might be here
public class ClientKeyFilter implements Filter {

  @Value('${CLIENT_KEY}')
  String clientKey

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
    req = (HttpServletRequest) req
    def reqClientKey = req.getHeader('Client-Key')
    if (!clientKey.equals(reqClientKey)) {
      throw new AccessForbiddenException('Invalid API key')
    }
    chain.doFilter(req, res)
  }

  public void destroy() {}
}
```

**AccessForbiddenException**

```
public class AccessForbiddenException extends RuntimeException {
  AccessForbiddenException(String message) {
    super(message)
  }
}
```

**ExceptionController**

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionController {
  static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionController)

  @ExceptionHandler(AccessForbiddenException)
  public ResponseEntity handleException(HttpServletRequest request, AccessForbiddenException e) {
    logger.error('Caught exception.', e)
    return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), I_AM_A_TEAPOT)
  }
}
```

Where I'm wrong? Can simple servlet filter work with spring-boot's exception mapping?

Comment: That will never happen for a filter. `@ControllerAdvice` is only useful for request reaching the `DispatcherServlet`, `Filter`s are always executed before that. Either put that logic in the filter or instead of a filter use a `HandlerInterceptor`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I've finally used `HandlerInterceptor`. If you'd like to add it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As specified by the java servlet specification `Filter`s execute always before a `Servlet` is invoked. Now a `@ControllerAdvice` is only useful for controller which are executed inside the `DispatcherServlet`. So using a `Filter` and expecting a `@ControllerAdvice` or in this case the `@ExceptionHandler`, to be invoked isn't going to happen.

You need to either put the same logic in the filter (for writing a JSON response) or instead of a filter use a [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) which does this check. The easiest way is to extend the [`HandlerInterceptorAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) and just override and implement the `preHandle` method and put the logic from the filter into that method.

```
public class ClientKeyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Value('${CLIENT_KEY}')
    String clientKey

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, Object handler) {
        String reqClientKey = req.getHeader('Client-Key')
        if (!clientKey.equals(reqClientKey)) {
          throw new AccessForbiddenException('Invalid API key')
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: May be it changed since you posted your answer, but the signature now is:
`public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception`

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `@ControllerAdvice`, because it gets called in case of an exception in some controller, but your `ClientKeyFilter` is not a `@Controller`.

You should replace the `@Controller` annotation with the `@Component` and just set response body and status like this:

```java
@Component
public class ClientKeyFilter implements Filter {

    @Value('${CLIENT_KEY}')
    String clientKey

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        String reqClientKey = request.getHeader("Client-Key");

        if (!clientKey.equals(reqClientKey)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Invalid API key");
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Servlet Filters in Java classes are used for the following purposes:

- To check requests from client before they access resources at backend.
- To check responses from server before sent back to the client.

Exception throw from Filter may not be catch by **@ControllerAdvice** because in may not reach DispatcherServlet. I am handling in my project as below:

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = null;
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (bearerToken != null && (bearerToken.contains("Bearer "))) {
            if (bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer "))
                token = bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
            try {
                AuthenticationInfo authInfo = TokenHandler.validateToken(token);
                logger.debug("Found id:{}", authInfo.getId());
                authInfo.uri = request.getRequestURI();
                
                AuthPersistenceBean persistentBean = new AuthPersistenceBean(authInfo);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(persistentBean);
                logger.debug("Found id:'{}', added into SecurityContextHolder", authInfo.getId());
                
            } catch (AuthenticationException authException) {
                logger.error("User Unauthorized: Invalid token provided");
                raiseException(request, response);
                return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                raiseException(request, response);
                return;
            }
```

// Wrapping the error response

```
private void raiseException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    apiError.setMessage("User Unauthorized: Invalid token provided");
    apiError.setPath(request.getRequestURI());
    byte[] body = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(apiError);
    response.getOutputStream().write(body);
}
```

// ApiError class

```
public class ApiError {
    // 4xx and 5xx
    private HttpStatus status;

    // holds a user-friendly message about the error.
    private String message;

    // holds a system message describing the error in more detail.
    private String debugMessage;

    // returns the part of this request's URL
    private String path;

    public ApiError(HttpStatus status) {
      this();
      this.status = status;
    }
   //setter and getters
```