# @ControllerAdvice doesn't handle exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.9 for developing my application. I need implement jwt authentication, and I used jjwt library. The following code is from my custom authentication security filter which inherits from `OncePerRequestFilter`. Here I tried to parse the username from token, when username is parsing automatically is jwt verified and also check expiration of token. I debug it and it works, so I next want to send the correct message to the client app why authentication failed. I want to throw an ExpiredJwtException and handle it with the controller advice where I format the output.

Here is exception throwing:

```
try {
    username = jwtTokenService.getUsername(authToken);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    logger.error("an error occured during getting username from token", e);
} catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
    logger.warn("the token is expired and not valid anymore", e);
    throw new ExpiredJwtException(e.getHeader(), e.getClaims(), e.getMessage());
}
```

And here is my controller Advice, JwtException is base class of ExpiredJwtException which I throw so it should work. I also tried directly use ExpiredJwtException in ExceptionHandler, but didn't work as well. Next I want to handle another exceptions with same way.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> handleException(Exception ex) {
        Map<String, Object> errorInfo = new HashMap<>();
        errorInfo.put("message", ex.getMessage());
        errorInfo.put("status", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        errorInfo.put("status_code", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorInfo, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(JwtException.class)
    //@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity handleJwtException(JwtException ex) {
        Map<String, Object> errorInfo = new HashMap<>();
        errorInfo.put("message", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        errorInfo.put("status", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        errorInfo.put("status_code", HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY.value());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorInfo, HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
    }

}
```

Here is my folder structure:
[image]

I want return just response with 4xx status, but I always got 5xx Internal error when my exception is thrown. Can you tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advice.

Comment: Do any of the exception handler methods get invoked?

Comment: @Synch I tried another another exception, e.g. runtime and also nothing was handled

Comment: Can you post the class and method surrounding your first code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your controller extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and have your exception handling methods take in the `WebRequest` as a parameter

Then change your return value to this

```
return handleExceptionInternal(ex, errorInfo, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
```

The `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` can be changed to any 40x error

Example for `Exception.class`

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleUncaughtException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {

  String message = "Something bad happened";

  return handleExceptionInternal(ex, message, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
}
```

According to this [Make simple servlet filter work with @ControllerAdvice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335157/make-simple-servlet-filter-work-with-controlleradvice) you can create a custom handler.

Then add your new handler to your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new CustomHandler());
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but doesn't work ... I still got Internal Server Error and controller advice didn't hit.

Comment: From what I am reading `ControllerAdvice`only works for exceptions thrown from `@Controllers`. Are you throwing those exceptions inside a Controller or a Service the controller calls?

Comment: Also please see this, it might lead to a solution as well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335157/make-simple-servlet-filter-work-with-controlleradvice

Comment: It looks like what I need ... I implement custom HandlerInterceptor ... but can tell me how to add it to my configuration? I am using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter ... is possible to add it here?

Comment: I added how to do it in my original post

Comment: thanks, but In my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is nothing method addInterceptors() to override :/

Comment: I tried add WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and add interceptor ... but it didnt works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164411/discussion-between-locus2k-and-denis-stephanov).

Comment: How did you solve it? I can't find the method to override in the class

Answer (score 5):

If the exception is thrown in filter, Springs exception handling (`@ControllerAdvice`, `@ExceptionHandler`) is not involved.
You need to catch all exceptions inside filter and work directly with `ServletResponse`.

As I understand - **Filters** are low level logic (request handling before spring infrastructure), but you can have a workaround, like a specific filter that wraps chaining and catches all `RuntimeExceptions`. (Looks like a crunch, but no other solutions).

If you want to have a specific login to create your exception object - override `ErrorAttributes` bean. It will allow you to have a single view for all application exceptions.

To directly specify http response status use
`httpServletResponse.setStatus(... your status code ...)`;

Comment: Your solution not works for me otherwise you was right with filter chain and exceptions ... T found this but I don't know how to use that handler ... can you help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335157/make-simple-servlet-filter-work-with-controlleradvice

Comment: Adding an interceptor to handle exceptions is also not the best idea.
` throw new ExpiredJwtException(e.getHeader(), e.getClaims(), e.getMessage());`. What is the problem to pass all this into ServletResponse directly?

servletResponse.sendError(code, e.getMessage())

Comment: I also have another idea ... it good practice to omit security filter, and parse and check request header in controller? next I can move logic into service and handle exceptions as well.

Comment: It is an awful idea, Denis. Please, respect SingleResponsibilty in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue in which RestControllerAdivce was not handling the exception, Thing is that advice method can have only those arguments in its signature which exception throwing method have or can provide. My AOP method was not having access to Headers so it could not provide Headers to RestControllerAdivce method. As soon as I created a new exception handler method in RestController without Headers as argument, RestControllerAdivce started working as expected. [Detials here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60890319/exception-in-spring-aop-itself-not-getting-handled-through-restcontrolleradvice)